# not getting text box when i click edit in gridview

Tags: c#

Code is not working When I click edit it is not showing any text box

```
protected void gdvDeptDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gdvDeptDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

public void BindData()

```
{
    con.Open();   
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from deptinfo",con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);        
        gdvDeptDetails.DataSource = ds;
        gdvDeptDetails.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Not sure... maybe because you're using RowEdit for it?

Comment: Please provide more information of BindData() function

Comment: Use `RowCommand` instead of `RowEditing`.

Comment: Can you paste code for your entire aspx grid view?

Answer (score 0):

'>

Convert your grid view fields in templates and give a text box in EditItemTemplate.